# How to submit a spark job in a 4 node CDH cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have a cluster with following configurations.

```
Distribution : CDH5,
Number nodes : 4,
RAM : 126GB,
Number of cores : 24 per node,
Harddisk : 5TB
```

My input file size is 10GB. It takes a lot of time (Around 20 mins) when I submit with following command.

```
spark-submit --jars xxxx  --files xxx,yyy  --master yarn /home/me/python/ParseMain.py
```

In my python code I am setting the following:

```
sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("myapp")    
sc = SparkContext(conf = sparkConf)    
hContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

How can I change the spark submit arguments so that I can achieve better performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some spark-submit options that you could try

```
--driver-cores 4
--num-executors 4
--executor-cores 20
--executor-memory 5G
```

CDH has to be configured to have enough vCore and vMemory.  Otherwise the submitted job would remain `ACCEPTED` it wouldn't `RUN`.

Comment: Hi Kenji Noguchi,

Comment: Hi Kenji Noguchi,

Thanks for your reply.
May I know how to configure vCore and vMemory?

Comment: Look for `Container Virtual CPU Cores Maximum` and `Container Virtual CPU Memory Maximum` in the Yarn configurations.